# How to create GUI with Tkinter? (macOS)

Tags: python, tkinter, macos-mojave

This might seem like a stupid question and it probably is, but I'm having a problem with Tkinter.
How does one create GUI application on Python for macOS?

I have already installed Python 3 as it was recommended and when I type
`from tkinter import *` on Sublime Text it gives me a following error: 
`"ImportError: No module named tkinter"` however when I do it on Terminal then it gives me no error. Python test app and everything works perfectly. How do I do those things on sublime text and other IDE editors?

I've seen videos etc how people are running Python on their text editors and when they press command + b or whatever it even pops up an empty window. How come I don't get it to work? I've installed Python 3 and everything. So what might be the issue here?

Comment: Try it with `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter` - if that works, your IDE is somehow configured to use Python 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @jasonharper - Thank you very much for your reply. I tried Tkinter and tkinter

Comment: Sorry, something happened and I couldnt finish my reply. Anyways, I've been doing upgrading to python 3 and downgrading to python 2 the whole day.

Comment: Oh my god! I am sorry for the massive replies, but I got it to work after rebooting my computer twice and reinstalling Sublime Text again and by setting up Python 3 in Sublime!
Thanks for helping me though!